# how to take input till "only" newline character or a space is inputted ?Basically how to run loop till you enter nothing as input?

Tags: c, loops, input, io

i am trying to create a looping which keeps looping till "only" newline charater is inputted or maybe just a space (until nothing is entered to the input line).

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        int num;
        while(1)
        {
            scanf("%d",&num);
            if(num==NULL)
                break;
        printf("%d",num);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with `scanf` (at least not easily). If you want to process user input, `scanf` is a bad choice (in fact, in all my years of developing in C, I've never used `scanf`; I recommend you avoid it altogether).

`num==NULL` makes no sense: `num` is a number, but `NULL` is a pointer value. If you want to check whether `scanf` was successful, you need to check its return value.

I'd do something like:

```
char line[100];
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {  // read input line by line
    int num;
    if (sscanf(line, "%d", &num) != 1) {  // the line didn't start with a valid integer
        break;
    }
    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

If you want to check specifically for an empty string, not just something that doesn't look like a number, you could use [`strspn`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html):

```
if (line[strspn(line, " \t\n")] == '\0') {
    // line contains spaces / tabs / newlines only
```

Comment: thank you the @melpomene the answer was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

There are other things that can be on a line other than an integer. Your code indicates an integer expected, but your text only indicates the line is blank or only contains a space.

Given your text in the question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char line[1024];

    while( fgets( line, sizeof( line ), stdin ) )
    {
        if(   (strlen( line ) == 1 ) 
          ||  (strlen( line ) == 2  && line[0] == ' '))
        {
            // all done
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // process line
        }
    } // end while
}
```